# Custom events in vue.js components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**The scenario**

Since I have a more complex checkbox I encapsulated it inside a separate component. Inside the template of the parent component I prefer using `v-model` to bind the value to a variable.

My approach is based on this description (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) taken from the official documentation.

**The problem**

When I have two `custom-checkbox`-elements and I select the last one, the first one inside the DOM will be selected. So it seems, that the first one is consuming the event.

**The code**

The following snippet illustrates the checkbox component.

```html
<template>
  <div class="checkbox-part">
    <input class="checkbox-part-input" type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb"
      v-bind:checked="checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
    <label class="checkbox-part-label" for="cb"
      :class="{ 'checkbox-part-label--checked': checked }"
    >
    <slot name="label"></slot>
    </label>
    <!-- removed for brevetiy -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I achieve, that the selected checkbox is updated?

Comment: This typically happens when they have the same `name` and `v-model` attribute. Did you make those unique?

Comment: The component itself is called `CheckboxPart`. The variable bound to `v-model` is called different in both parent components. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Can we see the code for that custom component?

Comment: Of course. I've just updated my post and included a snippet.

Comment: The name will always be the same. Can we see how you're passing `checked` in to the checkbox?

Comment: I'll extend my snippet. After checking my implemention I've recognized that id and name will always be the same. That's not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have name of input hardcoded in component. So you probably render two input with same name ("cb" in this case)
I think that you can pass input name and id as props.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! After checking my implementation and the hint of @Ohgodwhy I've set `id` and `name` as well as the value for the labels `for` attribute dynamically. So it will be passed in the template of the parent components.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the  comments the problem was caused by hard-coded values for `id` and `name` inside the `CheckboxPart` component.

I've added two properties for `name` and `value` and inject them into the component as well.

**The snippet**

```html
<!-- checkbox -->

<template>
  <div class="checkbox-part">
    <input class="checkbox-part-input" type="checkbox" 
      :name="name"
      :id="id"
      v-bind:checked="checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
    <label class="checkbox-part-label" 
      :for="name"
      :class="{ 'checkbox-part-label--checked': checked }"
    >
      <slot name="label"></slot>
    </label>
 
    <!-- removed for brevity -->
 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    model: {
      prop: 'checked',
      event: 'change'
    },
    props: {
      checked: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<!--- parent component using the one -->

<template>
  <!-- removed for brevity -->
  <!-- ... -->
 <div class="expandable-category-part-social-section">
        <checkbox-part
          v-model="isSocialIntegrationEnabled"
          :id="title + 'social-media'"
          :name="title + 'social-media'"
        >
          <template slot="label">
            <div class="checkbox-part-label-text">Final text comes here...</div>
          </template>
</checkbox-part>
</div>

<!-- ... -->

</template>
```